# jQuery issues in WordPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using owl carousel and slicknav in my WordPress localhost site. I am calling the jquery from my theme folder. I tried using `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` in my functions.php but if I do, then the owl carousel and slicknav don't work. And using that function, I can see jquery loaded in my source code.

Now, I have installed a plugin 'Fancybox for WordPress' and the plugin is not working. If I use `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` function instead of my theme folder's jquery, the plugin works but owl carousel and slicknav doesn't work.

I think the problem is happening because of my jQuery calling. I need a proper way to call jQuery and also I would like to avoid any confliction. That means there must be a way where I can use owl carousel, slicknav and anything else and also I can use plugins that require jQuery. How do I do that?

I have used the plugin in twentyfourteen theme and it works there fine.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you have jQuery loaded before your code? If you get "jQuery is undefined" error in console (F12), probably you need to change the script loading order.

It will be working:

```
<script src="path-to-jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   $('.foo').bar();
</script>
```

The code below won't be working:

```
<script>
   $('.foo').bar();
</script>
<script src="path-to-jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. yes, jQuery loaded before code, I can see that from my source code. but right now the problem is, Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(…) 

I think now the problem is happening for all those $ signs. I heard the error will be gone if I use 'jQuery' instead of '$' but how am I supposed to change all of them on owl carousel and other minified files? is there any quick way to fix??

Comment: You still have the same problem.Maybe jQuery is loaded asynchronously?

Comment: It will be great to see a live demo.

Comment: I am working on localhost but I surely understand how hard it is to answer without a live demo, thank you for trying. I fixed the problem. Replaced all the '$' signs with 'jQuery' and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Your problem was very interesting. There's also posibility that other library overwrites the "$" sign, which is an alias for "jQuery". In theory it should be:

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enqueue file in functions.php, you can't use directly wp_enqueue_script('jquery').

You need to use the action `wp_enqueue_scripts` then use `wp_enqueue_script('jquery')` in the callback function.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_my_js');

function enqueue_my_js(){
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'owl_caroussel', get_template_directory_uri().'owl_caroussel.js', false ); // adjust the file path & name
}
```

When you enqueue script that is dependent on jQuery, note that the jQuery in WordPress runs in noConflict mode, which means you cannot use the common $ alias. You must use the full jQuery instead. Alternately, place your code using the $ shortcut inside a noConflict wrapper.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
// $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
[ your code goes here ]
} );
```

Don't forget to enqueue the style files too if need.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for replying and yes I did that. but now I am having "Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function(…)", how do I get rid of that error?

Comment: I add the details about noConflict mode